# Update columns in UItable with timer in Matlab

Tags: matlab, timer, matlab-guide, matlab-uitable

I have a UItable with the 4 first columns that are being updated every 1 second with some external logger data. I would like to have a 5 column with a logical select column, so I could select which instruments to display.

The problem is the timer update the 'data' of the UItable, and I can't find a way to only update the first 4 columns without updating the last (5th) one.

Does anyone would have a solution ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: when the timer update the `data` of the `uitable`, does it send only new calculated values or does it get the `data` from the `uitable` first (then update a few fields and reset the `data`) ?

Comment: Currently it recreates a new cell array containing the new `data` ? You think I should get the `data` and then update only the column that I want to modify ? Is this efficient ? thanks.

Comment: no it's not efficient ... but it is the only way. Unfortunately `uitable` does not allow to update an individual element programmatically. You have to send the whole data every time.

Comment: anything in the java undocumented matlab maybe?

Comment: Maybe two tables is then better...

Comment: you'd better use java table directly then, because I don't remember any solution to the matlab `uitable` even in the undocumented articles (I haven't read them all though ... )